# Intercepting Exceptions with custom JSF event handlers

Tags: exception, jsf, actionlistener

Is there any way to create a custom `ActionListener` class in JSF so that I can intercept an exception if it occurs on pressing the command button using my own ActionListener class

I tried using the following code:

`firstpage.jsp`

```
<f:view>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>firstpage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h:form>    
        <h:commandButton id="button" value="submit"
                         actionListener="#{databasebean.fetchUserName}"/>
      </h:form>
    </body>
  </html>
</f:view>
```

`Dao.java`

```
package getexception;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

public class Dao {

    String firstname;
    private Connection con=null;
    private Statement stmt = null;
    private ResultSet rst = null;
    private ArrayList ar;
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + "new";
    public Dao() {

    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void fetchUserName(ActionEvent ae) throws Exception{
        Driver d= (Driver)Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rst=stmt.executeQuery("select firstname from employee where firstname like '%e'");
        if(rst.next()) {
            this.setFirstname(rst.getString("firstname"));
        }
        rst.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }}
```

`NewActionListener.java`

```
package getexception;

import com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl;
import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

public class NewActionListener extends ActionListenerImpl{

    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        System.out.println("try block");
        super.processAction(event);

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("catch block");
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application application = facesContext.getApplication();
        NavigationHandler navigationHandler = application.getNavigationHandler();
        navigationHandler.handleNavigation(facesContext,null,"exceptionNavigation");
        facesContext.renderResponse();
        }
    }}
```

`faces-config.xml`

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/JSF/Configuration">
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>databasebean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>getexception.Dao</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>

  <navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-outcome>exceptionNavigation</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/error.jsp/<to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>

  <application>
    <action-listener>getexception.NewActionListener</action-listener>
  </application>

  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>backing_hellopage</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>getexception.backing.Hellopage</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

`error.jsp`

```
  <html>
    <f:view>
      <head>
        <title>firstpage</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h:form>
          <h:outputText value="Exception succesfully navigated"/>
        </h:form>
      </body>
    </f:view>
  </html>
```

The code generated an SQL exception but it was not showing me the `error.jsp` page.

**What have I misconfigured so that the error page is not showing when an exception fired?**

Answer (score 3):

javadoc for [Application.setActionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#setActionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionListener)):

> Set the default ActionListener to be
>   registered for all **ActionSource**
>   components.

The [ActionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/event/ActionListener.html) set on an Application is not responsible for invoking other listeners. It does not call anything set via the [actionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/commandButton.html) attribute nor the [f:actionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/actionListener.html) tag. **It *is* responsible for processing the [action](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/commandButton.html) attribute**, which is bound to methods that return a navigation-case string (see get/setAction on [ActionSource](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource.html)).

So, the listener on the application can't catch events from other listeners because it doesn't call them.

Summary:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.foo1}" actionListener="#{bean.foo2}">
    <f:actionListener type="type.Foo3" />
</h:commandButton>
```

1. **foo1:** (method *public String foo1()*) uses faces-config [ActionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getActionListener())
2. **foo2:** (method *public void foo2(ActionEvent)*) uses [MethodExpressionActionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/event/MethodExpressionActionListener.html)
3. **Foo3:** (class *public class Foo3 implements ActionListener*) is registered directly on the component

---

As an aside, it is probably better to use this pattern to create the ActionListener registered in faces-config.xml:

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private final ActionListener delegate;

    public MyActionListener(ActionListener delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public void processAction(ActionEvent event)
            throws AbortProcessingException {
        delegate.processAction(event);
    }

}
```

When the JSF framework configures itself, it will pass the underlying ActionListener implementation to the constructor. This applies to many JSF artefacts (factories, etcetera).

Answer (score 1):

You have a unnecessary slash (/) in the line:

```
<to-view-id>/error.jsp/<to-view-id>
```

Should be

```
<to-view-id>/error.jsp<to-view-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find, how to [implement an Action Listener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaut.html#bnauv)

and here, how to [register a listener on components](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnasz.html#bnatb) (even an example for the commandButton).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
<from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
```

after navigation rule and before navigation case.